# Table element closes prematurely with javascript concatenation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to output a javascript object literal into a HTML table. Since I need to iterate through the object, I have separated the table header creation into a function, and the same with the table rows that are iterated from the object and lastly also a function that builds the table footer. Then one self executing function with three lines that execute these three functions to build my complete table.

The issue though is that the inner HTML of the footer is placed outside of the table (after it) and the footer elements are not generated at all. I've gone through the code multiple times and I cannot see any syntax error in the concatination either. Am I missing something in the code, or in the execution itself (some rule of thumb I don't know about or something)? My code:

[>>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmkprdf0/)<<]
The code is attached below for instant test.

**Javascript:**

```
var my_object = {
    prop1: ['<span class="mainItem">Item 1</span>', 220, 'show', 'count'],
    prop2: ['<span class="mainItem">Item 2</span>', 100, 'show', 'count'],
    get prop3() { //access with my_object.handledareutbildning
        return ['<span class="mainItem">Item 3</span>', this.prop3_1[1] + this.prop3_2[1], 'show', 'count'];
    },
    prop3_1: ['<span class="subItem">Item 3.1</span>', 300, 'show', 'noCount'],
    prop3_2: ['<span class="subItem">Item 3.2</span>', 300, 'show', 'noCount'],
    prop4: ['<span class="mainItem">Item 4</span>', 199, 'show', 'count'],
    get prop5() { //access with my_object.riskutbildning
        return ['<span class="mainItem">Item 5</span>', this.prop5_1[1] + this.prop5_2[1], 'show', 'count'];
    },
    prop5_1: ['<span class="subItem">Item 5.1</span>', 800, 'show', 'noCount'],
    prop5_2: ['<span class="subItem">Item 5.2</span>', 2000, 'show', 'noCount'],
    prop6: ['<span class="mainItem">Item 6</span>', 325, 'show', 'count'],
    get prop7() { //access with my_object.uppkorning
        return ['<span class="mainItem">Item 7 total</span>', this.prop7_1[1] + this.prop7_2[1], 'show', 'count'];
    },
    prop7_1: ['<span class="subItem">Item 7.1</span>', 800, 'show', 'noCount'],
    prop7_2: ['<span class="subItem">Item 7.2</span>', 400, 'show', 'noCount']
};

function itemRows() {
    let outputEl = document.getElementById("output");

    for (var key in my_object) {
        //if (my_object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (my_object[key][2] == 'show') { //the third value in the array of each prop!

            outputEl.innerHTML += '<tr><td class="left">' + my_object[key][0] + '</td><td class="right">' + my_object[key][1] + '</td></tr>';
        }
    }
}

function topRow() {
    let outputMainEl = document.getElementById("outputMain");
    outputMainEl.innerHTML += '<table><thead><tr><th class="leftHEAD">ToDo</th><th class="rightHEAD">Price</th></tr></thead><tbody id="output">';
}

function sumRow() {
    let outputMainEl = document.getElementById("outputMain");
    outputMainEl.innerHTML += '</tbody><tfoot><tr><td class="leftSUM">Sum:</td><td class="rightSUM">xxxx</td></tr></tfoot></table>';
}

(function renderContent() {
    topRow();
    sumRow();
    itemRows();

})();
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="outputMain"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/*region Righteous Font Import*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:200,400,700,900');
/*endregion*/

html {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}

body{
    background: #191c1f;
}

table {
    border-spacing: 5px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}

.left, .right {
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.leftHEAD, .rightHEAD, .leftSUM, .rightSUM {
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.leftHEAD, .rightHEAD, .leftSUM, .rightSUM, .mainItem {
    padding: 5px 15px;
}

.leftHEAD {
    background: hsl(192, 20%, 20%);
    color: #dcdcdc;
    text-align: left;
}

.rightHEAD {
    background: hsl(192, 20%, 20%);
    color: #dcdcdc;
}

.leftSUM {
    background: hsl(192, 20%, 20%);
    color: #dcdcdc;
    text-align: left;
}

.rightSUM {
    background: hsl(192, 20%, 20%);
    color: #dcdcdc;
}

.left {
    background: hsl(0, 0%, 20%);
    color: #dcdcdc;
}

.right {
    background: hsl(0, 0%, 40%);
    color: #dcdcdc;
    text-align:center;
}

.mainItem {
    font-weight: 400;
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 60%);
}

.subItem {
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 30px;
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 40%);
}
```

```js
var my_object = {
 prop1: ['<span class="mainItem">Item 1</span>', 220, 'show', 'count'],
 prop2: ['<span class="mainItem">Item 2</span>', 100, 'show', 'count'],
 get prop3() { //access with my_object.handledareutbildning
  return ['<span class="mainItem">Item 3</span>', this.prop3_1[1] + this.prop3_2[1], 'show', 'count'];
 },
 prop3_1: ['<span class="subItem">Item 3.1</span>', 300, 'show', 'noCount'],
 prop3_2: ['<span class="subItem">Item 3.2</span>', 300, 'show', 'noCount'],
 prop4: ['<span class="mainItem">Item 4</span>', 199, 'show', 'count'],
 get prop5() { //access with my_object.riskutbildning
  return ['<span class="mainItem">Item 5</span>', this.prop5_1[1] + this.prop5_2[1], 'show', 'count'];
 },
 prop5_1: ['<span class="subItem">Item 5.1</span>', 800, 'show', 'noCount'],
 prop5_2: ['<span class="subItem">Item 5.2</span>', 2000, 'show', 'noCount'],
 prop6: ['<span class="mainItem">Item 6</span>', 325, 'show', 'count'],
 get prop7() { //access with my_object.uppkorning
  return ['<span class="mainItem">Item 7 total</span>', this.prop7_1[1] + this.prop7_2[1], 'show', 'count'];
 },
 prop7_1: ['<span class="subItem">Item 7.1</span>', 800, 'show', 'noCount'],
 prop7_2: ['<span class="subItem">Item 7.2</span>', 400, 'show', 'noCount']
};

function itemRows() {
 let outputEl = document.getElementById("output");

 for (var key in my_object) {
  //if (my_object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
  if (my_object[key][2] == 'show') { //the third value in the array of each prop!

   outputEl.innerHTML += '<tr><td class="left">' + my_object[key][0] + '</td><td class="right">' + my_object[key][1] + '</td></tr>';
  }
 }
}

function topRow() {
 let outputMainEl = document.getElementById("outputMain");
 outputMainEl.innerHTML += '<table><thead><tr><th class="leftHEAD">ToDo</th><th class="rightHEAD">Price</th></tr></thead><tbody id="output">';
}

function sumRow() {
 let outputMainEl = document.getElementById("outputMain");
 outputMainEl.innerHTML += '</tbody><tfoot><tr><td class="leftSUM">Sum:</td><td class="rightSUM">xxxx</td></tr></tfoot></table>';
}

(function renderContent() {
 topRow();
 sumRow();
 itemRows();

})();
```

```css
/*region Righteous Font Import*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:200,400,700,900');
/*endregion*/

html {
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;
}

body{
 background: #191c1f;
}

table {
 border-spacing: 5px;
 border-collapse: separate;
}

.left, .right {
 padding: 5px;
 border-radius: 20px;
}

.leftHEAD, .rightHEAD, .leftSUM, .rightSUM {
 border-radius: 5px;
}

.leftHEAD, .rightHEAD, .leftSUM, .rightSUM, .mainItem {
 padding: 5px 15px;
}

.leftHEAD {
 background: hsl(192, 20%, 20%);
 color: #dcdcdc;
 text-align: left;
}

.rightHEAD {
 background: hsl(192, 20%, 20%);
 color: #dcdcdc;
}

.leftSUM {
 background: hsl(192, 20%, 20%);
 color: #dcdcdc;
 text-align: left;
}

.rightSUM {
 background: hsl(192, 20%, 20%);
 color: #dcdcdc;
}

.left {
 background: hsl(0, 0%, 20%);
 color: #dcdcdc;
}

.right {
 background: hsl(0, 0%, 40%);
 color: #dcdcdc;
 text-align:center;
}

.mainItem {
 font-weight: 400;
 color: hsl(0, 0%, 60%);
}

.subItem {
 padding: 5px 15px 5px 30px;
 color: hsl(0, 0%, 40%);
}
```

```html
<div id="outputMain"></div>
```

Comment: You can't insert partial elements into the DOM, fill them in, and then add closing tags. The DOM only accepts whole element objects....it isn't like a text editor which is the way your logic is treating it

Comment: Ok. That's constructive. It seems to work for the first half. How else would I iterate the rows? Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Right it's sort of working but the DOM has to basically self close the unclosed html. That's why your footer is not inside the table

Comment: If you want to do this with html strings (rather than creating elements like `document.createElement()`)...build the whole string....then insert only once at the very end

Comment: As for "what's the point" ... am trying to get you to re-think whole approach as well as understand why it's not working

Comment: So for example creating a full table in one string and adding some ID to each cell and that inject my props (with say .innerHTML) for each of them? That's what I can make of it now and that claches with the ability to iterate (as my skillset sees it).

Comment: Well I wrote the "what's the point" comment before you wrote the new one that actually had a point. Could have been avoided if you wrote both comments in the first one and it's irrelevant now.

Comment: Basic concept ... `var wholeTableHtml = getTableStart() + getTableRows() + getTableFooter(); outputEl.innerHTML = wholeTableHtml `. Each of those methods returns part of the html so once concatenated it is 100% complete and valid structure and then that gets inserted in DOM

Comment: I know this could have been made a TON easier with DIV's, since there is no "before" or "after" the iteration but DIV's don't paste into Excel.

Comment: Methods? What's inside them? Swapping that with what's in the self executing function, adding the "let" for "outputEL" and correcting their names doesn't do the trick. Why are you spending so much time being diffuse instead of just writing a proper answer?

Comment: being diffuse? Your expectations are too high here. Understand the concept of "teach a man to fish" vs "give a man a fish"?

Comment: Sure. Do you understand the concept that your teachings might not work if someone keeps telling you that what you are teaching is to little for them to understand? And yes, diffuse. Look it up (in a dictionary) <- that's teaching someone to fish with enough details.

Comment: In simpler terms make your current functions `return` the html string they are responsible for. Concatenate all those results together...then insert on string only in the DOM

Comment: You act like if a math  would refuse to show the formula before he teaches the components of it, and then expecting the students to draw it up because they have seen "some parts".

Comment: Dude...this is all volunteer help and not a free code writing service. Really time for you to drop the attitude if you want to get along here

Comment: Are you suggesting arguing with people and trying to be as little help as possible at the time is something you need to do because it's voluntary? What in the definition of "voluntary" requires giving people a hard time, or even wasting your own time with poor formulations that ultimately leads to.. *drumroll* a bad time for everyone involved? Like: now.

Comment: No I am simply saying your snotty attitude about level of expected details not being sufficient rather than asking friendly questions has now turned me off enough to ignore any further comments

Comment: And did I say it was a free coding service? If you haven't figured this out yet: 1) I did code, and it failed. I failed to see why, and I asked. 2) You choose to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by just merging the `topRow()` and `sumRow()` function and instead creating a `tableElement()` function with one HTML string made up of the two strings in the `topRow()` and `sumRow()` function (***that's it!***):

[>>[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmkprdf0/2/)<<]
The code is attached (and updated) below for instant test.

```js
var my_object = {
 prop1: ['<span class="mainItem">Item 1</span>', 220, 'show', 'count'],
 prop2: ['<span class="mainItem">Item 2</span>', 100, 'show', 'count'],
 get prop3() { //access with my_object.handledareutbildning
  return ['<span class="mainItem">Item 3</span>', this.prop3_1[1] + this.prop3_2[1], 'show', 'count'];
 },
 prop3_1: ['<span class="subItem">Item 3.1</span>', 300, 'show', 'noCount'],
 prop3_2: ['<span class="subItem">Item 3.2</span>', 300, 'show', 'noCount'],
 prop4: ['<span class="mainItem">Item 4</span>', 199, 'show', 'count'],
 get prop5() { //access with my_object.riskutbildning
  return ['<span class="mainItem">Item 5</span>', this.prop5_1[1] + this.prop5_2[1], 'show', 'count'];
 },
 prop5_1: ['<span class="subItem">Item 5.1</span>', 800, 'show', 'noCount'],
 prop5_2: ['<span class="subItem">Item 5.2</span>', 2000, 'show', 'noCount'],
 prop6: ['<span class="mainItem">Item 6</span>', 325, 'show', 'count'],
 get prop7() { //access with my_object.uppkorning
  return ['<span class="mainItem">Item 7 total</span>', this.prop7_1[1] + this.prop7_2[1], 'show', 'count'];
 },
 prop7_1: ['<span class="subItem">Item 7.1</span>', 800, 'show', 'noCount'],
 prop7_2: ['<span class="subItem">Item 7.2</span>', 400, 'show', 'noCount']
};

function itemRows() {
 let outputEl = document.getElementById("output");

 for (var key in my_object) {
  //if (my_object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
  if (my_object[key][2] == 'show') { //the third value in the array of each prop!

   outputEl.innerHTML += '<tr><td class="left">' + my_object[key][0] + '</td><td class="right">' + my_object[key][1] + '</td></tr>';
  }
 }
}

function tableElement() {
 let outputMainEl = document.getElementById("outputMain");
 outputMainEl.innerHTML += '<table><thead><tr><th class="leftHEAD">ToDo</th><th class="rightHEAD">Price</th></tr></thead><tbody id="output"></tbody><tfoot><tr><td class="leftSUM">Sum:</td><td class="rightSUM">xxxx</td></tr></tfoot></table>';
}

(function renderContent() {
 tableElement();
 itemRows();

})();
```

```css
/*region Righteous Font Import*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:200,400,700,900');
/*endregion*/

html {
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;
}

body{
 background: #191c1f;
}

table {
 border-spacing: 5px;
 border-collapse: separate;
}

.left, .right {
 padding: 5px;
 border-radius: 20px;
}

.leftHEAD, .rightHEAD, .leftSUM, .rightSUM {
 border-radius: 5px;
}

.leftHEAD, .rightHEAD, .leftSUM, .rightSUM, .mainItem {
 padding: 5px 15px;
}

.leftHEAD {
 background: hsl(192, 20%, 20%);
 color: #dcdcdc;
 text-align: left;
}

.rightHEAD {
 background: hsl(192, 20%, 20%);
 color: #dcdcdc;
}

.leftSUM {
 background: hsl(192, 20%, 20%);
 color: #dcdcdc;
 text-align: left;
}

.rightSUM {
 background: hsl(192, 20%, 20%);
 color: #dcdcdc;
}

.left {
 background: hsl(0, 0%, 20%);
 color: #dcdcdc;
}

.right {
 background: hsl(0, 0%, 40%);
 color: #dcdcdc;
 text-align:center;
}

.mainItem {
 font-weight: 400;
 color: hsl(0, 0%, 60%);
}

.subItem {
 padding: 5px 15px 5px 30px;
 color: hsl(0, 0%, 40%);
}
```

```html
<div id="outputMain"></div>
```